# jQuery adding blank option field in the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery code that is working for two select fields.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").change(function(){
      $('#trblock').fadeIn();
      if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
      }
      var id = $(this).val();
      var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
      $('#select2').html(options);
    });
});
```

However I want the second select box having id="select2" to be loaded with 1 extra blank option at the top. I tried simply adding the HTML part but I think that due to the jQuery code effect above its not allowing it. So I think modifying the jQuery part instead will do the task. But I have a newbie to jQuery. Please help me how to get it.

Something like this in HTML.

```
<select name="" id="select2">
<option value=""></option> // I want this here (by changing/adding codes in jquery)
<option value="1" date="01">Value 1</option>
<option value="2" date="02">Value 2</option>
<option value="3" date="03">Value 3</option>
<option value="4" date="04">Value 4</option>
<option value="5" date="05">Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the empty option, then add the rest with `.append()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").change(function(){
      $('#trblock').fadeIn();
      if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
      }
      var id = $(this).val();
      var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
      $('#select2').html('<option value="">').append(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: and where to place this code? can you just simply copy my code and update your code there?

Comment: I thought it would be obvious that it simply replaces the code you have that adds the options. But I guess not.

Comment: i think u missed a # here $('select2') as it states an id

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna add the blank option in the starting and select it by default, use below code:

```
$("#id").prepend("<option value=' ' selected='selected'></option>");
```

**prepend** will add the option to top and **selected='selected'** will make it selected. As **value=' '**, so, it is blank value option.

If you wanna just add the blank option and don't wanna select it by default then use below code:

```
$("#id").append("<option value=' ' ></option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

just use prepend() of jquery to add an option at the top.

```
$('#select2').prepend('<option value="">');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this if you are using form::select then use this inline [''=>'--- Select Subject -  --']+$subjects

```js
$('#subject').select2({
    placeholder: "Select Subject...",
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id ='subjectDiv'>
   <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('subject', '* Subject:') !!}
      {!! Form::select('subject', [''=>'--- Select Subject -  --']+$subjects, null, ['required' => true, 'class' =>       'form-control', 'id'=>'subject'])!!} 
      @if ($errors->has('subject'))
      <span class="text-danger">{!! $errors->           first('subject') !!}</span>
      @endif                               
      <small id="" class="form-text text-muted"></small> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```